# unable to create C++project, access to Engine\Intermediate\Build\BuildRules is denied

Tags: c++, windows, unreal-engine4

I copied the UE_4.22 folder to the Program Files\Epic Games directly (Epic Games folder also created by myself manually ). when I am trying to create a c++ project, i got the error: ***Unable to create directory 'C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.22\Engine\Intermediate\Build\BuildRules\UE4Rules.dll' for intermediate assemblies(Exception: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.22\Engine\Intermediate\Build\BuildRules' id denied***
But if create general blueprint project, it is all work fine.

If I copy the UE_4.22 folder to D disk, it is also work good with c++ project.
Seems some access right issue with C disk? But can't figure out what it actually is, someone have any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not supposed to write to `C:\Program Files` as a regular user. Move your build directory (or preferably the whole tree) somewhere else.

Comment: hi Botje,  What do you mean the build directory? Is that the location where I create my C++ project. If yes, i am already save the C++ project in D disk. UE_4.22 is the install folder which located in C disk.

Answer (score 1):

C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Intermediate\Build\BuildRules

1. User permissions for folders
2. Property -> Security
3. Edit User's permissions. Full control.